# Detox - How to get a previous spec to run before a new spec runs to avoid duplicate test steps?

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, detox, greybox

So I've wrote a test that logs in a user:

```
describe('Login', () => {

beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative()
  })

  it('Should grant access to a user with valid credentials', async () => {
    test code
  })
})
```

And now I'm writing a new spec to log out a user, so instead of writing the same test code again, I want the login spec to run within the log out spec. I would imagine it would look something like:

```
describe('Log Out', () => {

beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative()
    it ('Should grant access to a user with valid credentials')
  })

  it('A User Logs Out', async () => {
    test code
  })
```

How do I get Detox to run the first login test before continuing with the new steps?

The beforeEach it ('Should grant access to a user with valid credentials') doesn't work unfortunately, so I'm missing something in the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This has no relation to Detox, this describe/it API is related to the test runner you are using. Anyway, use functions:

```
describe('Login', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
    await grantAccessToUserWithValidCredentials();
  });

  it('A User Logs Out', async () => {
    // here the app is ready for you specific log out use case 
  });

  async function grantAccessToUserWithValidCredentials() {
    //grant it
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to use Drivers in your tests. 
You can check out these slides:
http://slides.com/shlomitoussiacohen/testing-react-components#/7